# What API to use for an App to access (send amount) Bitcoin Wallet

Tags: javascript, meteor, bitcoin

I have an existing Application that is deployed on iOS/Android/browser. It uses Meteor and is 100% javascript. I would like to enhance this application to access the local Bitcoin wallet and send small amounts from the wallet to a pre-defined address for escrow purposes. For clarity, the wallet belongs to the Wallet owner which is neither me nor my App. The App and Wallet are on the same device.

I therefore need an API that works across all the different wallets people install and want to avoid storing a private key on my application and would even like to avoid people having to create an account with my application.

So, the specific question is if there is an API that allows an App to instruct a wallet to send a bitcoin payment to an address. The user would be prompted to approve the transaction by the wallet. If such an API does not exists how could a solution to such a requirement be implemented?

Comment: Try using a `bitcoin:` URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend using a `bitcoin:` URI for this. Bitcoin URIs open in the user's default Bitcoin wallet. The syntax for a Bitcoin URI is as follows:

```
bitcoin:<address>[?amount=<amount>][?label=<label>][?message=<message>]
```

So for instance, if you want your user to send `0.1 bitcoins` to `175tWpb8K1S7NmH4Zx6rewF9WQrcZv245W`, you would use the following URI:

```
bitcoin:175tWpb8K1S7NmH4Zx6rewF9WQrcZv245W?amount=0.1
```

You can also optionally add a label using the `label` parameter, so the user knows where they are sending to.

More information on Bitcoin URIs: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0021

Comment: Do you have a sample of using js with the bitcoin:URI? I understand the syntax of the URI but am not sure how to invoke it or what API to use.

Comment: @cap_mkt_tools It's a URI, so all you need to do is construct a link and get the user to click on it. An example in HTML would be `<a href="bitcoin:1istendqWJ1mKvrdRUQZDL2F3tVDDyKdj?amount=0.1">Send Bitcoins</a>`.

Comment: Thank you. As it's for escrow purposes is there a standard way for my app to get acknowledgement that the amount at the new address has been confirmed. I do need to do an action only after the transaction has been cleared.

Comment: @cap_mkt_tools There is no standard way to get acknowledgement for a transaction, since it relies on a connection to the Bitcoin network itself - you'll need to use an external API (or a SPV client library) for that.